# show that inequality holds for $n \ge 10$

Tags: calculus, inequality

I want to prove that for $n \ge 10$ holds: $$(n+1)^{\sqrt{n+1}}<n^{\sqrt{n+2}}$$

I know that holds $(n+1)^{{n+1}}<n^{{n+2}}$ which can be proven by induction, but here I don't know how to deal with squares

Comment: Is $n$ an integer, or is $n$ a real number?

Comment: n is natural number

Answer (score 1):

Note that the desired inequality is equivalent to
$$
(n+1)^{1/\sqrt{n+2}} < n^{1/\sqrt{n+1}}.
$$
If we define
$$
f(x) = x^{1/\sqrt{x+1}},
$$
then it suffices to show that $f$ is decreasing for $x\ge10$. Equivalently, it suffices to show that
$$
\log f(x) = \frac{\log x}{\sqrt{x+1}}
$$
is decreasing for $x\ge10$; and this is a fairly standard calculus problem (indeed, it is increasing from about $x=9.19$ onward).